# Create array of objects with foreach loop in php

Tags: php

How I am currently doing it

```
$arr = array(
    array(
        'date'=>$response2->Msg[0]->Date, 'sender'=>$response2->Msg[0]->Sender, 'message'=>$response2->Msg[0]->Message
    ),
    array(
        'date'=>$response2->Msg[1]->Date, 'sender'=>$response2->Msg[1]->Sender, 'message'=>$response2->Msg[1]->Message
    )
);
echo json_encode($arr);
var_dump($response2);
```

The above code creates an array of objects which is what I need.
Example Output:

```
[{date":"06-Jan-20 04:00:00","sender":"dsdssf","message":"aaaaa},{date":"06-Jan-20 04:00:00","sender":"addfdfd","message":"ncccc2"]
```

I want to do the same thing with a loop to avoid repetition.

What I have tried

```
foreach ($response2->Msg as $key => $value) {
    $arr= array(
        'date'=>$value->Date, 'sender'=>$value->Sender, 'message'=>$value->Message
    );
}
```

The above code gives this output it stores the last object only

```
{"date":"06-Jan-20 04:00:00","sender":"addfdfd","message":"ncccc2"}
```

Comment: Switch `$arr=` with `$arr[] =` ... might be what you want.

Comment: Use `array_map()` to create one array from another array.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($response2->Msg as $key => $value) {
    $rec = array('date'=>$value->Date, 'sender'=>$value->Sender, 'message'=>$value->Message);
    array_push($arr, $rec);
}
```

Comment: There's no need to create another variable ($rec) and it's not recommended to use array_push() to add one element to an array, the best way is **$array[] = $new_item;** https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php